# How to fetch the URL of an uploaded IMAGE or VIDEO from a GOOGLE FORM using GOOGLE APP SCRIPT?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-editor

[image]I'm trying to create a google app script function where I want to fetch the URL of the image/video uploaded in the google form so that I can use it to display in my google web app. I'm not able to find any solution.

In the image below, the page source shows the URL of the image that was uploaded in the form. This URL is what I want from the app script.

Answer (score 1):

When a file is uploaded via a Google Form, the file is placed in a folder within the form owner's Google Drive.

If you are the form owner, a new folder will be created within your drive and you will be able to access them using the Google Drive API.

Check out the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

If you know the name of the form, you can search the Folder within your drive and then use the API list the files within that folder using files.list .

You can find the fields within Files here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files and can use these fields to any specific URLs.

Comment: Just a note on this: you can actually use the Drive API in Apps Script. Simply go into your script **Resources-> Advanced Google Services -> Enable Drive API**. Also, with plain Apps Script you can only get the image of a Google Form question **IF** this image is in an **Image Item** as stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms#imageitem).

Comment: 1. Going through all the files in the user's drive doesn't seem like the right thing to do and even if I do, how do I map the image in the drive with the one in the form? Is there a specific ID that maps those two?


                                                                                                                                    2. Let's say I found the mapping between the picture in google drive and the forms, how do I get the URL of that particular picture?

Comment: Go here: https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/ . Within the form, in responses, you will have the option to create a spreadsheet from your responses. Create it and the url will be in that sheet.